# Style native JavaScript Notification

Tags: javascript

I was browsing MDN and noticed there's now native JS support for a desktop notification, but did not see an option to style it. (I realize it is not widely supported yet.)

Is that option available?

I do see in the spec that there are some properties, such as body, icon, and tag that we can pass through as options, but it doesn't look like we can pass HTML into them and have it compiled. I do see that they only accept strings, but was wondering if someone has figured out a way to style it that I haven't.

```
dictionary NotificationOptions {
  NotificationDirection dir = "auto";
  DOMString lang = "";
  DOMString body;
  DOMString tag;
  DOMString icon;
};
```

Use case: passing in a URL and allowing the user to click on the URL.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GentleMaN/9j2gtxjd/2/) I have been playing around with.

Not a dire need, just more of a curious question.

Comment: It looks like in the [old spec](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications/api-specification) there was a way to use HTML, but that's gone in the latest version.

Comment: For your use case, is there only one URL for the user to click?

Comment: @summea Sure, we can go with that. Whether it's a URL, button, whatever.

Comment: @MarkC. In that case, would adding logic to [`Notification.onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/onclick) work?

Comment: @summea I think so, but from a UX perspective it's a little too bare-bones. While you prove a good point, I was coming at this question from more of a UX perspective. Making it green or red, adding a button or anchor tag, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem logical to treat it like an alert box, since it is also a popup.
The alert box is a system object which cannot be styled and does not interpret the text as HTML.